# How to divide across columns in data frame?

Tags: r

I am looking to divide across all my columns in my data frame, but divide all my columns by the same column (and then multiply by 100).

Here is an example with data:

Before:

```
         0       4       7       12
Sub1    0.26    0.21    0.18    0.146
Sub2    0.35    0.24    0.30    0.293
Sub3    0.30    0.24    0.26    0.261
```

After:

```
         4        7      12
Sub1    80.8    83.6    82.3
Sub2    70.6    123.6   96.8
Sub3    82.6    107.6   99.5
```

(0.21 / 0.26) * 100 = 80.8

(0.18 / 0.26) * 100 = 83.6

(0.146 / 0.26) * 100 = 82.3

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? What have you tried so far?

Comment: How did you get the second column or the third column? Your computation might be having a hiccup..`0.146/0.18*100` which is `81.11111` and not `82.3`

Comment: So each of those columns are divided by that first column.
(0.21 / 0.26) * 100 = 80.8
(0.18/ 0.26) * 100 = 83.6
(0.146/ 0.26) * 100 = 82.3